# Extract Values between Open/Close Tags

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have many records from a database that have a field with the following appended:

```
...blah blah. <edited><editID>variable-text-here</editID><editDate>variable-date-here</editDate></edited>
```

In my C# code I want to get the variable-text and variable-date out of each, to use within my program.

What would be the best/most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: How about using an... XML parser?

Comment: Definitely use an XML parser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regular expression, something like:

```
Match result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(inputString,"<editID>.*</editID>");
Match result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(inputString,"<editDate>.*</editDate>");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This looks good SoMoS - Though it does also bring back the surrounding tags - any way of getting just the values between the tags?

Comment: The easiest way is to put a .Replace("<editID>","") as an example on the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<editID>[\s\S]*?</editID>
```

Or deal it as xml.